# How to understand "as often as not" literally?

Tags: phrases

Here is the item "as often as not" in Oxford dictionary.

> **as often as not** quite frequently or commonly: I had two homes really, because as often as not I was down at her house.

So I know it means commonly. But is it possible to get that meaning from the phrase itself literally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“X occurs as often as Y” means that the frequency of X is the same as the frequency of Y.

> I am at her house as often as *I am at my house*.
>   I am at her house as often as *I am **not** at her house*.

These sentences are technically correct (but awkward). “I am at her house” is repeated here and can be omitted.

> I am at her house as often as […] not […].

Thus, literally, “as often as not” means “exactly half the time”. In fact, idiomatically, it means more often than one might expect, or more often than *uncommonly*.